# Wicket inheritance and editing component values of Base Page.

Tags: label, wicket

Currently I have my base page, which defines the menu, content, heading, and footer divs. I set my child to be inside the content area.. but I have a title bar that goes across the top between my header and content page.. In here (the title bar) I set a Label, that labels which menu item page the user is currently on.

When I go to the child page, I want that menu bar's title to change to the name of the child page.. is there a way to change this label of the parent's component from the child's code?

I tried using getParent().add(new Lable....)   and that didn't work.. So as of right now, in the parent page I just have a static string that I change before each onClick which works, but I feel there is probably a better way using a model.. Which I'm still understand how those work.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried overriding this String in your children class? Would give this approach a try...

Comment: Can you give an example of this? I'm new to Wicket, and basically I'm trying to access a Label with a wicket id of the parent from its child.  I don't see the connection of overriding the string class.  

Thanks.

Comment: Will answer the question, but you might have to provide with some code, not 100% sure if it will work but it should...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public abstract class ParentClass extends Page {

    public ParentClass(String title) {
        Label pageTitle = new Label("title", title);
        add(pageTitle);
        //add header, footer, and all you need...
    }
}
```

And your child class:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    private static final String TITLE = "This is the title of the ChildClass";

    public ParentClass() {
        super(TITLE);
        //all the other code...
    }
}
```

Have you tried this approach? Since all your pages have to inherit from ParentClass, and ParentClass cannot be instantiated, it should do the work...

My sample is made assuming you are using this pattern to add header and footer:

http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/markupinheritance.html

Comment: Hey thanks, That didn't work. But for now I just change the static value in the child class, and that works on load. As before I was changing the static value before navigating to new page, but this seems to work and read better. Thanks Martin!

Comment: You have many options, maybe even send the value to the parent class as a model and then load it from database. However, if you just need static title, it's much of a mess...